# Page gets downloaded to a bin file instead opened

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, mobile

I have a wordpress website with customized Avada theme.

There is this strange bug that happens on mobile devices, when you try to click on a certain items from navigation, the page it leads to gets downloaded to a file called "downloadfile.bin" on mobile or "download" on desktop chrome version (mobile mode).

I tried everything, searched for a similar issue but nothing. There are many plugins installed but nothing related to cache management (the first thing that crossed my mind). I ran out of ways to approach this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It was an NGINX problem.

I just removed `default_type application/octet-stream;` line. 
It made browser think it's some binary data and not HTML.